# A family of events such that all proper subfamilies are independent, but the entire family is not

Tags: probability

I'm trying to find an example for $n$ events such that each $k$ ($k < n$) are independent, but the $n$ events together are dependent.

Two events are independent if the probability for both of them to happen equals to the product of the probability of each one separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you toss a coin $n-1$ times. For $i$ from $1$ to $n-1$, let $A_i$ be the event that the $i$th toss comes up heads. Let $A_n$ be the event that the total number of tosses that came up heads is even. Then $\{ A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n \}$ is dependent but every proper subset is independent.